# use strcat with strcpy occur problems

Tags: c, strcpy, strcat

I have a problem when use strcat function. I have no idea.please help me.thanks

```
char dst[5]="hello";
char *a = "12345";
char *b = "54321";

//work
strcat(strcpy(dst, a), b);
printf("one==%s\n",dst);

//error
strcpy(dst, a);
strcat(dst, b);
printf("two==%s\n",dst);
```

Comment: you are just lucky that first case is working.

Comment: @Dayalrai That sort of "luck" leads to satellites crashing and people dying when the conditions change.

Comment: what does "luck" mean?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with both versions is that you are writing past the end of `dst`. Both `a` and `b` require six bytes including the NUL terminator; `dst` only has space for five.

This results in [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The nature of undefined behaviour is such that it may or may not manifest itself. If it does, it could be in fairly arbitrary ways.

Answer (score 0):

You dont allocate correctly your memory on your dst pointer, here is a working code:

```
int             main()
{
  char *dst;
  char *a = strdup("12345");
  char *b = strdup("54321");

  dst = malloc(100);
  dst = strdup("hello");                                                                             
strcat(strcpy(dst, a), b);
printf("one==%s\n",dst);                                                                                
strcpy(dst, a);
strcat(dst, b);
printf("two==%s\n",dst);
}
```

Comment: When dealing with `char`, it is unnecessary to have `(sizeof (*dst))`; the C standard explicitly defines the size of `char` as 1.

Answer (score 0):

**PROGRAM:**

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
 {
        char dst[15]="hello";
        char *a = "12345";
        char *b = "54321";

        //work
        strcat(strcpy(dst, a), b);
        printf("one==%s\n",dst);

        //error
        strcpy(dst, a);
        strcat(dst, b);
        printf("two==%s\n",dst);
        return 0;
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
# 1:   hide   clone   input   8 seconds ago
result: success      time: 0s    memory: 2684 kB     returned value: 0

input: no
output:
one==1234554321
two==1234554321
```

EDIT:
Instead of 15 you can use 11 as well.. hope you understood the purpose of your code..

Comment: You can indeed make `dst` smaller than `15`, but it should be at least `11` characters long to account for the final `0`

Comment: I mean when the size of dst is 5, strcat(strcpy(dst, a), b) is working,why?